# Class Diagram with no Link

Tags: java, class, class-diagram

After downloading a repository of a java software (http://sourceforge.net/projects/gcs-java/) I used Enterprise Architect in order to create some class diagrams for me, example:

[image]

From another question I posted, my understanding is that each arrow shows a 'has' relationship, which basically shows how objects can hold instances of other objects. However, what about these objects that have no links to others? All these objects inside the class diagram are part of the same class, so does the fact that there are no links just simply mean that they handle a method that is isolated and does not effect any of the other objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow represent *association*.  To implement *has* relationship (aggregation), you use diamond in the owner side.  That standalone class do not have line because you do not have other classes that are associated to them.  Ex: `ScrollToSelection` class use `Outline` class but you don't have `Outline` class in your diagram.

Comment: So, can I still include the standalone class inside the class diagram?